# How to import custom views into your Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, view, gradle

Sorry if this is against any rules but I asked here and other places and received 0 working answers so I was looking to make this post so when someone Google's what I did, they'll see the solution.

This is how to use *someone else's* View in your project (noob level):

Some notes before we start:

- You do NOT need to drag and drop ANY files to use the View.
- You have to edit a file in your project that you wish to use the View in order to use it.
- Just having the View contents (not zipped/compressed) on your PC is enough for your project to recognize that the View exist's.
- This may or may not work the same for Eclipse, I am not sure, however if you are using Eclipse it would be a good idea to switch to Android Studio as Eclipse is no longer supported and is rough around the edges.

**New we start:**

1) Create a project in Android Studio - If you already have a project that you want to use this View in, skip this step.

2) Download the View you are looking to use, for the sake of demonstration, we'll use this one: https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker

3) Once you have downloaded that, you need to unzip it because it comes zipped in a WinRAR file, where you unzip it to DOES NOT MATTER.

4) Read the 'Dependency' that it tells you to add on the info/documentation page in the link above (every View should have this). In this View, it tells us to add "compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'" to the dependency; if you don't know what the dependency is and where it is, that is OK.

4a) The dependency is a method/line in a file called 'build.gradle' located IN OUR PROJECT LOCATION. If your project location is 'C:\Android Studio Projects\TestProject1' then the file you need to edit is located at 'C:\Android Studio Projects\TestProject1\app', it is called either 'build.gradle' or 'build' and is a GRADLE type file, either way, it is the only file called 'build' the other 'build' is a folder (which we don't want).

Note: It doesn't matter where you project is located, so long as you find your project directory, you can find the 'app' folder which contains the 'build.gradle' file.

4b) The 'build.gradle' file should look like this when opened:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kaio37k.brad.wakemeupagain"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
    compile 'com.github.pavlospt:circleview:1.2'

}
```

Note: So long as the format and method names are the same as what I listed, you are ok, the information such as Application ID, and all the compile lines WILL BE DIFFERENT if you are using a different View.

5) After you have opened the correct 'build.gradle' file, go down to the 'dependencies' method and underneath all of the compile lines add the dependency that you are told to add at the info page of your View.

```
dependencies{
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.github.pavlospt:circleview:1.2'

}
```

Add `compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'` to the bottom of that list.
It should now look like this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
compile 'com.github.pavlospt:circleview:1.2'

}
```

Note: Because you need to add that line to the dependencies of every project you wish to use it in, it will only show up in THIS project. If you want to use it in another project, add that line to the dependencies of THAT projects build.gradle.

6) Open Android Studio and do the following, click `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` then click `Build -> Rebuild Project`. Your View is now integrated however it may not show up on the Design Palette but that is OK.

7) First of two ways to use it,

A) Go to `Palette -> Custom -> The View you integrated` and it will then prompt you to drag and drop it in a location on screen. It will automatically show up in your XML to edit.

B) Add `<com.larswerkman.holocolorpicker.ColorPicker` then press `Ctrl + Space` and select the View you would like to add (i.e. the View you just added) to the XML; the view will automatically be placed in your `Design` tab.

Note: The `<com.larswerkman.holocolorpicker.ColorPicker` line will be different if it is a different app, the format will be the same `com.authorName.className.viewName` though.

**FIN**

I hope this helps, I tried to make it as descriptive as possible for the fact that I am new to this and everything anyone said went right over my head as it was not 'noob-friendly'. I do not browse this site often so I may not get back to you if you reply but I'll certainly try.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. If you wish to contribute this sort of material, post a question, then [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266672/is-it-appropriate-to-summarize-information-in-a-question-which-is-not-a-quest and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309689/what-to-do-with-a-question-which-isnt-a-question-but-a-tutorial/309693.

Comment: @CommonWare Will do!